# Formatting SQL friendly Date/Times in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I am building some test scenarios for my application. In order to do this, I have some code that is generating some SQL to help me test properly. A sample of the SQL that is generated is shown here:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(
 [ID],
 [Name],
 [CheckInDate],
 [CheckOutDate]
)
VALUES
(
  1,
  'A title',
  'Sat, 17 Dec 2011 14:33:12 GMT',
  'Sat, 17 Dec 2011 15:13:12 GMT'
)
```

When I attempt to execute this SQL, I receive the following:
*Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

How can i format the date/time strings so that SQL Server 2008 will accept them? I really need my C# code to generate the SQL (including the date/time items) to create my tests properly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way to solve this is to use the **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion) - note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

Comment: Or use parameterised queries, specify the type and let the wonderful world of libraries handle it for you?

Comment: @Dems: agreed - that's even better - but **if** you need strings for whatever reason - use the ISO-8601 format....

Comment: I'm still getting the error. I'm generating my date/time like the following. What am I doing wrong? checkInDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss")

Comment: @MonoDeveloper: if you use the format with the time - you need to separate the time portion from the date with a **`T`** : `checkInDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

So your command would be:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(
 [ID],
 [Name],
 [CheckInDate],
 [CheckOutDate]
)
VALUES
(
  1,
  'A title',
  @CheckInDate,
  @CheckOutDate
)
```

And you'd insert the dates like so:

```
SqlParameter checkin = new SqlParameter("@CheckInDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
SqlParameter checkout = new SqlParameter("@CheckOutDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);

checkin.Value = DateTime.Today; // Format these to the desired dates
checkout.Value = DateTime.Today;

command.Parameters.Add(checkin);
command.Parameters.Add(checkout);
```

Comment: You should drop the quotes around the parameters in your SQL, or you'll get a literal string `'@CheckInDate'`

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to not format dates at all, parameterize your `insert` statement, and pass dates as command parameters.

Comment: Your second point is a good one.  Read @marc_s answer, however, and you will find that your first point has *no* guarantee of working.

Comment: Whether it does depends on the server and the client's settings: the server's because it must also accept dd mm yyyy order, the client's because / uses the client's date separator, which you're hoping will match the server's.